# What affects manufacturing costs?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've been noticing that as I progress through my game on Classic Ironman, the cost for me to manufacture satellites keeps going down. It was §100 when I started the game, at another point it was §78, and now it's down to §70.

What affects the cost of manufactured goods? Number of engineers? Workshops? Something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cost discount falls off quickly with number of engineers, and is capped at 50%. The formula is

Project cost = Base cost * (0.5 + 0.5 * (Minimum engineers / Available engineers))
That is,

- with double the required engineers you get 25% discount,
- with four times the required engineers you get 37.5% discount,
- with infinity engineers you get 50% discount.

Also, there is a 7% rebate for adjacent workshops, but AFAIK, that is returned after the project completes.

Comment: is that 7% applied to the cost before or after the engineer cost reduction?

Comment: Not sure. But I'd guess after - it'd be too cool to have this at base cost, considering you can stack several of that 7-percents with multiple workshops.

Comment: yea, I'm guessing getting extra resources/money back after construction would be too good :P

Answer (score 3):

The workshop has an adjacency bonus of reducing manufacturing costs if they are next to another workshop.

Also, various continents have full coverage bonuses that can further reduce manufacturing costs.

Finally, the more engineers you have the cheaper it is to produce items.

Comment: I think there's a tooltip that also mentions the number of engineers matters, but I'm AFX at the moment and can't check...

Comment: @agent86 me too, I will update my answer once I go home and check

Comment: I can confirm the tooltip.

Comment: Anyone know if that tooltip is visible in the console versions somehow?

Comment: How much does each additional Engineer reduce manufacturing costs by?

Comment: @Wipqozn I don't know, I've never kept track of that.