# How much do additional engineers reduce manufacturing costs?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What affects manufacturing costs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87628/what-affects-manufacturing-costs)

There's a tooltip that mentions that more engineers will decrease the cost of building items (and facilities?). How much does each additional engineer lower costs? A fixed amount or percentage? Is building additional workshops cost effective after you already have the minimum number of engineers required to build what you need?